# get codeigniter page output and place it on non-codeigniter site

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hey guys was hoping you could help me out.

I am working on a site that essentially has two parts, one in codeigniter and one in non-codeigniter(i.e in magento).

I know this is a bad idea to begin with, but too late now.

Now thing is, I need a particular page's output AS-IS from the codeigniter site on the other site (the page is basically a search page). And I need this to be a backend solution for SEO so iframe wont do.

Both sites are hosted on the same domain.

I considered using CURL library to get the output of that page (after sending it post or get) and display it, but I am guessing that would be very inefficient.

Is there any other way?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do Cross-Domain Ajax using jQuery JSONP. [jQuery JSON Docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

You could also do on the other page

```
<?php echo file_get_contents("http://...yoururl..."); ?>
```

[file_get_contents docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

Something Else Useful perhaps **ob_start()**

**Example in Controller:**

```
function search() {
  ob_start();
  /* Your Controller Code as normal */

  $saved_output = ob_get_clean();
  /* Now you have output in a variable as-is and you can send it out */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A better way would be get page answer in xml, json and "draw" it in Magento. But as far as I understand you can't, so your chance would be retrieve page through cURL call or through [buffering output](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php), you should make some benchmark to compare two ways.